# How to pass Styled-Component theme variables to Components?

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Within my React+StyledComponent app, I have a theme file like so:

theme.js:

```
const colors = {
  blacks: [
    '#14161B',
    '#2E2E34',
    '#3E3E43',
  ],
};

const theme = {
  colors,
};

export default theme;
```

Currently, I can easily use these colors to style my components like so:

```
const MyStyledContainer = styled.div`
  background-color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors.blacks[1]};
`;
```

**The problem is, how do I pass blacks[1] to a Component as the prop of the color to use like so:**

```
<Text color="black[1]">Hello</Text>
```

Where Text.js is:

```
const StyledSpan = styled.span`
  color: ${(props) => props.theme.colors[props.color]};
`;

const Text = ({
  color,
}) => {
  return (
    <StyledSpan
      color={color}
    >
      {text}
    </StyledSpan>
  );
};

Text.propTypes = {
  color: PropTypes.string,
};

export default Text;
```

Currently the above is silently failing and rending the following in the DOM:

```
<span class="sc-brqgn" color="blacks[1]">Hello</span>
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: Updated to use styled-components `withTheme` HOC

**New answer**

You could wrap the component rendering `<Text>` in the higher order component (HOC) `withTheme` provided by styled-components. This enables you to use the theme given to the `<ThemeProvider>` directly in the React component.

Example (based on [the styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#getting-the-theme-without-styled-components)):

```
import React from 'react'
import { withTheme } from 'styled-components'
import Text from './Text.js'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <Text color={this.props.theme.colors.blacks[1]} />;
  }
}

export default withTheme(MyComponent)
```

Then you could do

```
const MyStyledContainer = styled.div`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;
```

**Old answer**

You could import the theme where you render  and pass `<Text color={theme.blacks[1]} />`.

```
import theme from './theme.js'
...
<Text color={theme.colors.blacks[1]} />
```

Then you could do

```
const MyStyledContainer = styled.div`
    background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `defaultProps`

```
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

MyStyledContainer.defaultProps = { theme }
```

Answer (score 1):

`App.js`

App gets theme and passes color to Text

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

const Text = styled.div`
  color: ${props => props.color || 'inherit'}
`

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    const { theme } = this.props
    return (
      <Text color={theme.colors.black[1]} />
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

---

`Root.js`

Root component passes theme to entire application.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components'
import theme from './theme'
import App from './App'

class Root extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <App />
      </ThemeProvider>
    )
  }
}

export default Root
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using functional components in React and `v4.x` and higher styled-components, you need to leverage `useContext` and styled-components' `ThemeContext`. Together, these allow you to **use your theme settings inside of components that *aren't* styled-components**.

```
import { useContext } from 'react'
import { ThemeContext } from 'styled-components'
    
export default function MyComponent() {
      
  // place ThemeContext into a context that is scoped to just this component
  const themeProps = useContext(ThemeContext)

  return(
    <>
      {/* Example here is a wrapper component that needs sizing params */}
      {/* We access the context and all of our theme props are attached to it */}
      <Wrapper maxWidth={ themeProps.maxWidth }>
      </Wrapper>
    </>
  )
}
```

Further reading in the styled-components docs: https://styled-components.com/docs/advanced#via-usecontext-react-hook